# Bulk insert directory of JSONs into single mongodb collection in parallel

Tags: mongodb, bash, mongoimport

The following works for us, importing the single file **our_file.json** into our mongodb collection: `mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@our-cluster.dwxnd.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection our_coll_name --drop --file /tmp/our_file.json`

The following does not work, as we cannot point to a directory **our_directory**: `mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@our-cluster.dwxnd.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection our_coll_name --drop --file /tmp/our_directory`

We predictably get the error `Failed: error processing document #1: read /tmp/our_directory: is a directory`

Is it possible to import all of the JSONs in **our_directory** into our collection using a single bash command? See speed test in my answer below - is it possible to parallelize, or use multi-threading, so that the mongoimport of the 103 files outperforms the mongoimport of the 1 file?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `cat /tmp/our_directory/*.json | mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@our-cluster.dwxnd.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection our_coll_name --drop` is working. And the import seems to be happening at a decent speed...

**Edit: Speed Test (locally on Mac with these specs)**

[image]

It took 11 minutes to mongoimport a total of 103 files with combined size of ~1GB to our mongoDB collection. We tested the mongoimport speed with a single 1GB file as well (rather than 103), and it took roughly 11 minutes as well.